# Defining 'edit' method to let admins change pending status of users in devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I've been following the wiki for Devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Require-admin-to-activate-account-before-sign_in. I get the page to display perfectly and everything but once I try to hit edit to change a user's status from pending to approved I get the error 'The action 'edit' could not be found for UsersController'.

I'm assuming I need to define the 'edit' method in my users_controller.rb file...I'm just not sure how I would code it tell the database to switch the user's status from pending to approved.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki just gives you the index action and view. You'll also need edit and update controller actions and an edit view for users with a form containing an "approved" checkbox (or select box, whatever floats your boat).

Comment: Any ideas on the best ways to do this?

Comment: I'm happy to help but we need to stick to specifics. The best way to do what, exactly?

Comment: The best way to create the edit method. So far my edit method looks like this 


    `def edit`
    `@user = User.find(params[:id])`
    `if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])`
      `#success`
    `else`
      `#failure`
    `end`
    `end`

I am not sure if one of the params needs to be the approved parameters that I need to change or if those params just refer to the specific table. And then I don't know what i should do for success and failure to make the database update.

Comment: The edit method is the `GET` action. The update method is your `PUT` action. You want call update_attributes in the update method. If the only form element in the edit view is "approved" then that's the only thing that will appear in `params[:user]`.

Comment: I'm confused...so how do i update the approved column on my database?

Comment: The only thing the edit method does is assign `@user = User.find(params[:id])` which is then presented in the edit view. The form in the edit view points to `update_user_path(@user)` so when you submit it, it hits the update method in the controller. In the update method, you once again assign `@user = User.find(params[:id])`. And because the form in your edit view only contains one attribute, an "approved" checkbox, that's the only thing that gets updated when you call `@user.update_attributes(params[:user])'.